# DatePicker in ko template

Tags: knockout.js

I have a foreach in ko template and inside i want to bind the datepicker.How it can be done

```
<script type="text/html" id="Date_List">
       From &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id = "DateFrom" name="DateFrom" data-bind="value: Queries()[0].QueryValueFrom" class="calendar" /><br/><br/>
    To &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id = "DateTo" name="DateTo" data-bind="value: Queries()[0].QueryValueTo" class="calendar" />
</script>
```

When I bind this with for each loop .
I cannot get the calendar pop up

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom datepicker binding, I have one in my collection of bindings

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings

```
<input data-bind="datepicker: date, datepickerOptions: { minDate: date }" />
```